# Access model's attrubutes inside of ModelView class

Tags: python, flask, flask-admin

Sorry in advance if it's a stupid question, but I am still a bit confused. Reading the flask admin documentation hasn't given any result yet.

In this example [flask admin image upload example](https://github.com/flask-admin/flask-admin/blob/master/examples/forms/app.py) there is a custom ModelView called ImageView:

```
class ImageView(sqla.ModelView):
    def _list_thumbnail(view, context, model, name):
        if not model.path:
            return ''

        return Markup('<img src="%s">' % url_for('static',
                                                 filename=form.thumbgen_filename(model.path)))

    column_formatters = {
        'path': _list_thumbnail
    }

    # Alternative way to contribute field is to override it completely.
    # In this case, Flask-Admin won't attempt to merge various parameters for the field.
    form_extra_fields = {
        'path': form.ImageUploadField('Image',
                                      base_path=file_path,
                                      thumbnail_size=(100, 100, True))
    }
```

In the `_list_thumbnail(view, context, model, name)` there is parameter model. Inside of this method I can access the attributes of the model.

My question is how can I access the model and its attributes outside of the `_list_thumbnail(view, context, model, name)` method but inside ImageView?

Thanks

Comment: flask-admin model views use class attributes to define the way they interact with models. Model is passed to [view constructor](https://github.com/flask-admin/flask-admin/blob/master/flask_admin/model/base.py#L767) as argument so you cannot access model on class level. But in view methods you can get it via `self.model`. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: @SergeyShubin, What I try to achieve is before saving the image to base_path = `file_path`, I want to append to the `file_path` id of the model. Do you have any idea how I can do that?

Comment: @Nurzhan I can't understand `append to the file_path id of the model`.

Comment: @stamaimer, This is the part I am interested in `form_extra_fields`. The I want to append  to the `file_path` which is just some path 'files/...' string 'user_' + model_id which will result in something like 'files/user_1', 'files/user_2' etc.

Comment: This statement override the field named `path` with `form.ImageUploadField`. The first parameter `Image` is the label of the input when render it to html. The second parameter is path to save the uploaded image file. The third parameter is the size of thumbnail of the uploaded file which can be omitted.

Comment: @stamaimer Thanks for the explanation but I already know it. The problem is in how I can modify the path using the model's attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing model data to fields defined in view could be painful. But luckily [FileUploadField](http://flask-admin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/mod_form_upload/#flask_admin.form.upload.FileUploadField) and its subclasses can get `namegen` function for generating names as an argument. It receives "dirty" model object as an argument:

```
def name_generator(obj, file_data):
    return 'file_%d.png' % obj.id

class ImageView(sqla.ModelView):
    form_extra_fields = {
        'path': form.ImageUploadField('Image',
                                      base_path=file_path,
                                      namegen=name_generator,
                                      thumbnail_size=(100, 100, True))
    }
```

I also found out that generated filename may contain path to the file, not only the name of the file.

**Update:** As @stamaimer found, this method doesn't work properly for objects which don't exist in database yet as they don't have IDs yet.

Comment: The file_data is a `File Storge` object instead of a model object.

Comment: @stamaimer Oops, my mistake. Thanks!

Comment: Have you try this code? I think the process of upload image file is during the   construction of the current instance. So the instance isn't created when the `namegen` is called.

Comment: I have write a demo to try this code. It will return `None` from `obj.id`.

Comment: @stamaimer It looks like it works properly on existing objects, new objects don't have IDs yet. I'm afraid this limitation cannot be easily worked around.

Comment: @SergeyShubin, Thanks for the help. I tried your answer. Not exactly what I wanted but it's ok.

Comment: @SergeyShubin Yes, So I advice to use other field instead of the primary key.

Answer (score 0):

As I commented in the first answer, You can't access the id of the current instance of the model. In spite of the instance is created, it haven't be commited to the database. There is no primary key of the current instance. But the other field is existence, maybe you can use other field instead of the primary key.