# Convert relationship query object representation to string in Flask-Admin form field

Tags: python, flask, flask-admin

I've implemented a categories feature for sorting posts on a simple blog, but Flask-Admin presents the query object representation in category field on the create/edit pages.

I'd like to display the `name` field of each category in the dropdown menu rather than the query object representation, i.e.:

`Cool Stuff` instead of `<Category 'Cool Stuff'>`

I suspect that this can be accomplished by specifying a label name using the `form_args` attribute on the ModelView with something like:

```
form_args = dict(
    category=dict(label=model.name)
)
```

However, I don't know how to access the model from within the ModelView class. I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43337820/access-models-attrubutes-inside-of-modelview-class), but it appears to be a specific rather than general solution that doesn't apply in my case.

Moreover, the [source code](https://flask-admin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/flask_admin/model/base/#BaseModelView) indicates that the model is expected to be available, but doesn't specify how to access it.

How can the model be accessed from within ModelView? If this is not possible, is there another solution to the query object representation issue?

EDIT:

Here's the code I have so far:

*models.py*

```
class Post(db.Model):                                                           
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)                                
    title = db.Column(db.String(80), index=True, unique=True)                   
    content = db.Column(db.UnicodeText)  # arbitrary/variable length string     
    slug = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True)                    
    img = db.Column(db.String(64))  # url of associated image file              
    date_created = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=db.func.current_timestamp())  
    date_modified = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=db.func.current_timestamp(), onupdate=db.func.current_timestamp())             

    # Relationships                                                             
    category_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('category.id'))

class Category(db.Model):                                                       
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)                                
    name = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True)                    
    slug = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True)                    

    posts = db.relationship('Post', backref='category', lazy='dynamic')         
    projects = db.relationship('Project', backref='category', lazy='dynamic')   

    def __repr__(self):                                                         
        return '<Category \'{}\'>'.format(self.name)
```

*routes.py*

```
class PostModelView(ProBlogModelView):                                          
    form_overrides = dict(content=CKTextAreaField)                              
    form_excluded_columns = ['id', 'slug', 'date_created', 'date_modified', ]   
    form_args = dict(                                                           
        title=dict(validators=[InputRequired()]),                               
        content=dict(validators=[InputRequired()]),                             
        img=dict(label="Image URL", validators=[InputRequired()]),              
    )
```

Flask-Admin appears to use a dropdown menu by default to present the set of existing categories on the Edit and Create pages for the Post model. The options contained in that menu should the `__repr__` value for each instance of the Category model, rather than its name attribute. My goal is to have the name displayed instead of the `__repr__` value.

I've done this in the main list table for the Post admin area by using `column_formatters`, but I'm not clear on how to do the same within the Edit/Create page forms.

Comment: Post what code you've got so far? Your question is  a bit hard to follow right now.

Comment: Updated post with code to clarify.

Comment: You can also this to your model: `def __str__(self): return self.name`